# Get the error in firebase api in the console and not working firebase

Tags: javascript, html, video, video-streaming, firebase

Error in console when I used firebase for streaming

> Uncaught Error: new Firebase failed: First argument must be a valid
>   firebase URL and the path can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]".

Comment: So, the natural question is, what are you putting the URL? It's conventional to post the code here on SO.